# Different instance variables show same value when using get method

Tags: java, return-value

I have this piece of code:

```
class Test {
 public static void main (String[] args){
  Base b1, b2;
  b1= new Base(1);
  b2= new Base(2);

  System.out.println(b1.getX());
  System.out.println(b2.getX());
 }
}


public class Base {
 static int x;
 public Base(){
  x=7;
 }

 public Base( int bM) {
  x=bM;
 }


 public int getX() {
  return x;
 }
}
```

I was told that this program will return the values 2 and 2 but I cannot understand why. According to what I know it should show 1 and 2. Can someone explain or give a link to an explanation? Thank you.

Comment: The clue is in the word `static`. This should help you out: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I should probably add that using statics like that is not considered good programming practice by most developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared x as a static member. A `static` member is shared by all instances of the same class.

```
static int x;
```

This is why the output is `2 and 2`
If you want that every instance of the class Base has its own value of the member x, you must remove the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**Static** means that it belongs to class, not instance, i.e. it shared by all instances of the class.